# Solving a first order differential equation - does it matter where you put the absolute value sign?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Problem:

Solve the following differential equation:
$$ 6x^2y \, dx - (x^3+1) \, dy = 0 $$

Answer:

\begin{align*}
 6x^2 \, dx - \dfrac{ (x^3+1)}{y} \, dy &= 0 \\
 \dfrac{ 6x^2}{x^3+1} \, dx - \dfrac{ dy}{y} &= 0 \\
2 \ln{\left( x^3+1\right) } - \ln{|y|} &= C_1 \\
\ln{ \left( \dfrac{ (x^3+1)^2}{|y|} \right)  } &= C_1 \\
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ (x^3+1)^2 = c|y| $$
However, the book gets:
$$ (x^3+1)^2 = |cy| $$
Are the answers equivalent? If not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: In the fourth line, it should be $2\ln |x^3+1|=\ln ((x^3+1)^2).$ However i think the answers are equivalent, since $c=e^{C_1}>0.$

Comment: I would say that $y= C(x^3+1)^2$ is the best way to write the solution.  This allows the solution $y=0$, which yours does not.

Comment: I agree with @GEdgar. But between $(x^3+1)^2=c|y|$ and $(x^3+1)^2 = |cy|$, these are equivalent, because $(x^3+1)^2\geqslant 0$. So if it is equal to $c|y|$, this forces $c\geqslant 0$, and $c=|c|$, whence $c|y|=|c||y|=|cy|$.